# Convert Military Time to Standard Time Error

Tags: sql, teradata, datepart

I have a data set that pulls back visit time in hour/min format (e.g. - 12:33PM would be 1233). I am trying to use the `DATEPART` function but it keeps giving me a syntax error stating that :

> "expecting something between '(' and the 'HOUR' keyword.

The section below is the piece of the SQL that is giving me errors:

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR , VSL.VISIT_TIME) > 12  THEN DATEPART (HOUR, VSL.VISIT_TIME) -12 ELSE DATEPART (HOUR, VSL.VISIT_TIME) END AS THE_TIME
```

I am trying to just get the hour part of the time.

Comment: What's your dbms? What's `VSL.VISIT_TIME` type?

Comment: If you are using SQL-Server, it worked http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/23692

Comment: I am using Teradata SQL assistant. VSL.VISIT_TIME is the column name in the table that includes the time of visit.

Comment: `DATEPART` is not a Teradata function. What is the datatype of `VSL.VISIT_TIME`?

Comment: I tried using EXTRACT as well but I got an error saying that "Select Failed 5326 Operand of Extract function is not a valid data type or value.  VSL.Visit_time is the table column that contains the time of visit. @dnoeth

Comment: Are you saying that the data in the column is actually stored as `1233`?  That's certainly not a timestamp, Based on your error, it's probably stored a numeric type.

Comment: 1. What is the data type of `VSL.VISIT_TIME` (SHOW TABLE <whatever the vsl table is>) 2. Share some sample values of the `VSL.VISITTIME` column. From that we can help craft a query to convert formats.

Comment: The data in visit time is stored in the following format (Hour Minute) so 10:00am would be stored in VSL.VISITTIME  as - 1000, and 2:20pm would be 1420, 6:30pm would be 1830 etc. @Andrew

Comment: @JNevill see above

Answer (score 0):

Doing this through a series of casts, you could do something like:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST((1420 * 100 (FORMAT '99:99:99')) AS CHAR(8)) AS time ) AS TIME FORMAT 'HH:MIBT') AS CHAR(8))
```

Or you could use some math to sort it out and cast at the end:

```
SELECT 
  1420 AS intTime,
  FLOOR(intTime/100) AS intHours,
  intTime - (intHours * 100) AS intMinutes,
  intHours * 60 + intMinutes AS totalIntMinutes,
  TIME '00:00:00' + (totalIntMinutes * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) AS totalTime,
  CAST(CAST(totalTime AS TIME FORMAT 'HH:MIBT') AS CHAR(8)) AS char12HrTime
```

Or just parse and math the thing:

```
SELECT 
  1420 AS intTime,
  Trim(CASE WHEN FLOOR(intTime/100) > 12 then FLOOR(intTime/100) - 12 ELSE FLOOR(intTime/100) END) || ':' || TRIM(intTime - (FLOOR(intTime/100) * 100))
```

There's probably a few other ways to cut this up, perhaps a little more elegantly.

Either way you cut it this is going to be a little ugly since you are storing time as something other than a `time` type.