# Select Failed 2620

Tags: sql, casting, extract, teradata

I am getting a fail from an EXTRACT function, See below:

```
EXTRACT (HOUR FROM time_cook)
```

The "time_cook" was not in the time format initially so I had to manipulate the record to get it to the format I wanted first, I used the statement below to format the record, I'm not sure if this is why the previous extract statement is giving me the select fail but I figured the more insight I share the better:

```
CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST((VSL.VISIT_TIME * 100 (FORMAT '99:99:99')) AS CHAR(8)) AS TIME ) AS TIME FORMAT 'HH:MIBT') AS CHAR(8)) AS TIME_Cook,
```

I am pulling from Teradata using Teradata SQL Assistant

Comment: Please edit the tags and include the language and environment you’re doing this so people know what it’s about

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You got an `HHMI` numeric value and want to convert it to a `TIME`? Then use `CAST(CAST((VSL.VISIT_TIME * 100 (FORMAT '99:99:99')) AS CHAR(8)) AS TIME(0))`

Comment: I am just trying to get the hour out of the time and not the minutes @dnoeth

Comment: If the datatype is an INTEGER: `VSL.VISIT_TIME / 100`, otherwise `CAST(VSL.VISIT_TIME AS INT)/ 100`

Comment: And `(cast(VSL.VISIT_TIME as decimal (10,2))) mod 100` will get you the minutes.  However, if all the casts your were offered in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200255/convert-military-time-to-standard-time-error) didn't work, I don't know if any of this will either.